# Python Google Image Download Library Error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-image-search

I'm writing a program to download google images to train a machine learning software that differentiates cubes and spheres. It worked with less than 100 items, but I cannot get it to work with more. I have installed chrome and webdriver, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Here's my code:

```
# importing google_images_download module 
from google_images_download import google_images_download
import os
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Users/Rick/Desktop/imagecollector/chromedriver.exe')

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Rick\\Desktop\\imagecollector")

# creating object 
response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()  

search_queries = [ 
'cube', 
'sphere'
] 


def downloadimages(query): 
    # keywords is the search query 
    # format is the image file format 
    # limit is the number of images to be downloaded 
    # print urs is to print the image file url 
    # size is the image size which can 
    # be specified manually ("large, medium, icon") 
    # aspect ratio denotes the height width ratio 
    # of images to download. ("tall, square, wide, panoramic") 
    arguments = {"keywords": query, 
                 "format": "jpg", 
                 "limit":1000, 
                 "print_urls":True,
                 "chromedriver": "C:/Users/Rick/Desktop/imagecollector/chromedriver.exe"} 
    try: 
        response.download(arguments) 

    # Handling File NotFound Error     
    except FileNotFoundError:  
        arguments = {"keywords": query, 
                     "format": "jpg", 
                     "limit":4, 
                     "chromedriver": "C:/Users/Rick/Desktop/imagecollector",
                     "print_urls":True,
                     "size": "medium"} 

        # Providing arguments for the searched query 
        try: 
            # Downloading the photos based 
            # on the given arguments 
            response.download(arguments)  
        except: 
            pass

# Driver Code 
for query in search_queries: 
    downloadimages(query)  
    print()
```

Here's the giant error:

```
C:\Users\Rick>"C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\imagecollector\python.exe - Shortcut.lnk" C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\imagecollector\imgcollector.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54256/devtools/browser/3455790f-5cc6-46ea-979c-489ff96c0324

Item no.: 1 --> Item name = cube
Evaluating...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54270/devtools/browser/b0f22738-fcce-4ea1-af32-4f1ff8a107a5
[0521/011849.633:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(122)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
[10852:8492:0521/011851.858:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(208)] [01:18:51.857] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1060 Getting Default Adapter failed.
[0521/011855.467:INFO:CONSOLE(490)] "%c%s color: red; background: yellow; font-size: 24px; WARNING!", source: https://www.gstatic.com/_/mss/boq-search/_/js/k=boq-search.VisualFrontendUi.en_US.tTUE-qzbW_Y.es5.O/am=RAIIUpjfCBFECAAwfBiAQAZIIAACIgARAAHEAQAAAIALBAAAAKAiAAAgi4A/d=1/excm=_b,_tp,searchview/ed=1/dg=0/wt=2/ct=zgms/rs=AH7-fg6TbeOc2pt8D6xXVK7ABSDBdg0eNQ/m=_b,_tp (490)
[0521/011855.468:INFO:CONSOLE(490)] "%c%s font-size: 18px; Using this console may allow attackers to impersonate you and steal your information using an attack called Self-XSS.
Do not enter or paste code that you do not understand.", source: https://www.gstatic.com/_/mss/boq-search/_/js/k=boq-search.VisualFrontendUi.en_US.tTUE-qzbW_Y.es5.O/am=RAIIUpjfCBFECAAwfBiAQAZIIAACIgARAAHEAQAAAIALBAAAAKAiAAAgi4A/d=1/excm=_b,_tp,searchview/ed=1/dg=0/wt=2/ct=zgms/rs=AH7-fg6TbeOc2pt8D6xXVK7ABSDBdg0eNQ/m=_b,_tp (490)
Getting you a lot of images. This may take a few moments...
Reached end of Page.
Starting Download...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\imagecollector\imgcollector.py", line 55, in <module>
    downloadimages(query)
  File "C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\imagecollector\imgcollector.py", line 34, in downloadimages
    response.download(arguments)
  File "C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\imagecollector\env\lib\site-packages\google_images_download\google_images_download.py", line 833, in download
    paths, errors = self.download_executor(arguments)
  File "C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\imagecollector\env\lib\site-packages\google_images_download\google_images_download.py", line 960, in download_executor
    items,errorCount,abs_path = self._get_all_items(raw_html,main_directory,dir_name,limit,arguments)    #get all image items and download images
  File "C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\imagecollector\env\lib\site-packages\google_images_download\google_images_download.py", line 763, in _get_all_items
    image_objects = self._get_image_objects(page)
  File "C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\imagecollector\env\lib\site-packages\google_images_download\google_images_download.py", line 753, in _get_image_objects
    image_objects = json.loads(object_decode)[31][0][12][2]
  File "C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Guessing `arguments` in `response.download(arguments)` isn't JSON data as the library expects it to be.

Comment: @Torxed I don't know what exactly you mean by that, but the code works when I set the limit to 100 or less. The path to chromedriver.exe is correct, and the format seems correct to me. Any other suggestions?